# Magento 2: New customer attribute not saving on admin

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom-attributes

I created new custom customer attribute, it is added to admin edit customer page but its value cannot be saved.

In /Vendor/Module/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

```
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

protected $eavConfig;

public function __construct(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    Context $context,
    CacheInterface $cache,
    CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
    Config $eavConfig
    ) {
    $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
} 

public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
    $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
    $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
} 

public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


    $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'invoice_email',
        [
        'label' => 'invoice email',
        'system' => 0,
        'position' => 100,
        'sort_order' =>100,
        'visible' =>  true,
        'note' => '',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'input' => 'text',

        ]
        );

    $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'invoice_email')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['customer_account_edit']) -> save();


} 

public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

} 

public function getEavConfig() {
    return $this -> eavConfig;
} 
}
```

And in Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace Wetag\InvoiceEmail\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
* @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
/**
 * EAV setup factory
 *
 * @var EavSetupFactory
 */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Wetag\InvoiceEmail\Setup\CustomerSetup');
            $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



    }

}
}
```

How can i edit the attribute so it can be saved in front end and baackend (i tried to create an observer but this return an infinite page loading when saving the customer: infinite loop)

Answer (score 1):

You define what forms appear in as part of setup. Have you missed this part?

https://github.com/DominicWatts/EmailCC/blob/master/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Xigen\CC\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install email_cc customer attribute
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'email_cc', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Email CC',
                'input' => 'text',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'position' => 500,
                'system' => false,
                'backend' => '',
                'user_defined' => true,
                'note' => __("Comma separated"),
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'email_cc')
            ->addData(
                [
                    'used_in_forms' => [
                        'adminhtml_customer',
                        'adminhtml_checkout',
                        'customer_account_create',
                        'customer_account_edit',
                    ],
                ]
            );

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I missed which part?

Comment: @tarekfellah used in forms part.  have you got all the forms?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, i changed the file Vendor\Module\Setup\UpgradeData.php and execute

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Vendor\Module\Setup\UpgradeData.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;



class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
/**
 * Customer setup factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory
 */
private $customerSetupFactory;

/**
 * Init
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
{
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * Upgrade data for a module
 *
 * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
 * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
 * @return void
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{


    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.0.3', '<')) {

        $this->createMobileAttribute($setup);
    }
}


public function createMobileAttribute($setup)
{
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    // Add new customer attribute
    $customerSetup->addAttribute(
        Customer::ENTITY,
        'invoice_email_1',
        [

            'label'                 => 'Invoice Email ',
            'input'                 => 'text',
            'required'              => false,
            'sort_order'            => 1000,
            'position'              => 1000,
            'visible'               => true,
            'system'                => false,
            'is_used_in_grid'       => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'    => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'default'               => '0'
        ]
    );

    // add attribute to form
    /** @var  $attribute */
    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'invoice_email_1');
    $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit']);
    $attribute->save();

    $setup->endSetup();
}
}
```